# @html.Listbox("someName",Model.Items) works but @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.items) does not work Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

ERROR TYPE: Output false false false for @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)

Expected Result: Listbox with the name of users.

## ViewModel

```
public class NewVariance
    {
        MVRLinqDataContext LinqCtx = new MVRLinqDataContext()
        public NewVariance()
        {
            IndividualsObjectTest();//load data dropdown and listbox data
        }

        public MultiSelectList Items { get; set; }

        //loads the values of the MultiSelectList above
        public void IndividualsObjectTest()
        {
            var IndividualsDropDownList =
                        (
                        from x in LinqCtx.ViewIndividualDropDownBoxes
                        orderby x.FullName
                        select x);

               Items = new MultiSelectList
              (
                IndividualsDropDownList as 
System.Collections.IEnumerable, "First_Hospital_Case_Nbr", "FullName"

              );

        }
```

## Controller

```
public class NewVarianceController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
       {
              var model = new NewVariance();
              return View(new model);
        }

    }
```

## View

```
@Html.ListBox("d",Model.Items)   THIS WORKS 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items) THIS DOESNT WORK OUTPUTS FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Why not use `@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Items)`? Also, do you have a specific editor template for `MultiSelectList`? I doubt you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An editor template simply renders some [default output](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) based on the property type. You need to personalize it if you expect to do something useful. You can read more about templated helpers on [this blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/). You cannot expect that a default editor template would know that you want it to render a listbox for this given property. So you could write a custom editor template and personalize this behavior.

Comment: So basically put it 
@model NewVariance
@Html.ListBox("d",Model.Items)    in a partial view in EditorTemplates

Comment: @jvelez, actually it's gonna be `@model IEnumerable<ItemType> @Html.ListBox("d", Model)` because you will invoke it like this `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Items)` so you will be passing a collection to this editor template.

Comment: I tried that i am getting html.helper does not contain a definition for MultiSelectList

Comment: @jvelez, well, that's normal. I've never heard of such helper built into ASP.NET MVC. The helper is `Html.ListBox`. `MultiSelectList` is a  class that you should pass as a second argument to the Html.ListBox helper.